# Are distress calls used in simulators?

Tags: emergency, flight-simulator, atc-simulator

Would a pilot flying in a flight simulator with VATSIM make a mayday call in a scenario in which a pilot in a real plane would?

Comment: Why wouldn't he? A flight simulator is a procedural trainer. A mayday call is as much a part of an emergency procedure as anything else he might practice.

Comment: @AdityaSharma oops, VATSIM. Autoincorrect "fixed" it for me.

Comment: You would get a better answer asking a forum of VATSIM users. This site is generally for real-life aviation; asking what people do in their hobby at home is not really on topic here IMO.

Comment: @Ben well, it's like your opinion man. I am a PPL student, and VATSIM+MSFS helps me a lot. For instance, in preparing for those emergency calls I certainly hope I will never have to make IRW. Besides, OP did not mention he/she is using the sim as a hobby. Simulators are very much used in the industry, and certainly not for gaming...

Comment: @CTZStef I'm not denying that home simulators, when used properly, can be helpful for training, but the majority of its users are hobbyists. Asking "what do people do on VATSIM?" is much better asked on a forum dedicated to VATSIM or at least online gaming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a real Level D simulator, you perform for the instructor as it it was real life and that includes radio calls. Unless the instructor tells you not to bother.

For VATSIM, you should go on the controller's VATSIM discussion board and ask if emergencies are encouraged. Some of the controllers on VATSIM are real life controllers and would probably enjoy the change of pace, and so would most of the other flight sim participants for that matter.  But I would check with the community first.

Comment: What if someone is flying a simulator for practice without an instructor? I was thinking of people running FlightGear, X-Plane, or a similar program on a home computer too, not just commercial training simulators.

Comment: @Someone, Nobody can answer for what an individual at home might do...

Comment: @someone I'm going to suggest that the bigger question if working in a multi user environment like VATSIM, should you even have faults etc turned on? Messing with someone else's practice by showing up and calling emergency is potentially very antisocial. Would suggest it only be done with prior discussion to whoever is running ATC at the time, and do not know enough about the online systems to say how to do that.